# SVN checkout with SVN protocol

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I've been using SVN a lot as a single user on a single computer

Now I'd like to share my stuff across multiple computers

So far I've been checking out from `file://c:/myproject`

I'd like to checkout from `svn://mycomputer/myproject`

How can I map the first into the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repository is laid out identically. In order to use the svn protocol to access the repository, you need to set up svnserv, and point it to the repository you're using. This will allow both accesses - file:// locally, and svn:// remotely (or locally). A colleague swears by [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

Answer (score 13):

You need the svnserve deamon.
The documentation to configure it is here (paragraph on "svnserve as Windows service"):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking

You may also want to look at other possibilities to acccess you svn server in this chapter.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how the paths would translate in Windows, but on Linux you need to start the svnserve daemon with repository root specified:

```
svnserve -d -r /path/to/repos/
```

Hence, if your svn repository is stored in `/path/to/repos/myproject`, the above would allow you to checkout from another computer by doing

```
svn co svn://your.ip.addr/myproject ./myproject_checkout
```

This would be different if you wanted to use the `svn+ssh` protocol, in which an svnserve process is created for every repository access request. This means that you don't need to spawn your own svnserve daemon, ssh takes care of that for you. This is surprisingly simple to setup for a single user. For more on that, SliceHost has a great article [here](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/9/5/using-ssh-with-svnserve).

Answer (score 1):

Little known fact: If you're a single user and your repository lies on a *nix-based PC which you can SSH to, you won't even need a server.

Just use the command:

```
scn checkout svn+ssh://USERNAME@mycomputer/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/REPOSITORY
```

This will prompt you for your SSH password (=login to mycomputer).